# Cant repost data fetched from get request to a new table as a post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hello i am developing an Admin dashboard for my company as this is first project with no prior backend and handling data experience, please any one here can help me out to complete my first project in react js

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you give us a few more specifics of what type of help you are looking for? What have you tried so far. Where is it that your are getting stuck?

Comment: please add more information to your question, we dont know your code ;)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.